# R: Improving efficiency of getting sum of differences in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

## Purpose:

`past` vector is the set of `o3.cpt`s found in the past period.
`current` vector is the set of `o3.cpt`s found in the current period.
Each `o3.cpt` has a set of numbers that are associated with the code (PCs in `numbers` data frame).
I am trying to get the sum of differences of PCs for every pair of past and current `o3.cpt`.
In the original dataset, there are more than 700 PC columns in `numbers` data frame.

## Question:

The below code is what I am currently using, but it is running too slow (I need to repeat this process for more than 700,000 times).
Would there be more efficient way to compute these `sum_diff`?

## Example dataset:

```
  past = sample(1:40, 20, replace=F)
  current = sample(41:80, 20, replace=F)
  
  set.seed(100)
  
  numbers <- 
    data.frame(
      o3.cpt = c(past, current),
      PC1 = runif(length(c(past, current)), min = -3, max = 3),
      PC2 = runif(length(c(past, current)), min = 1, max = 10),
      PC3 = runif(length(c(past, current)), min = -4, max = 2),
      PC4 = runif(length(c(past, current)), min = -9, max = 8),
      PC5 = runif(length(c(past, current)), min =  4, max = 9)
      )
  
  pairs <- 
    expand.grid(
      past,
      current
    )
```

## Current code:

```
if(nrow(pairs) > 0){
    sum_diff <- 
      pairs %>% 
      ddply(c('Var1', 'Var2'), function(j){
        
        p <-  
          numbers %>% 
          filter(o3.cpt == j$Var1[1]) %>% 
          select(starts_with('PC')) %>% 
          t %>% 
          data.frame %>% 
          .$.
        
        c<-  
          numbers %>% 
          filter(o3.cpt == j$Var2[1]) %>% 
          select(starts_with('PC')) %>% 
          t %>% 
          data.frame %>% 
          .$.
        
        data.frame(diff = sum(abs(p - c)))
      
    })
  }
```

## Extended example dataset and the current code

## Extended example dataset

```
d<-
      structure(list(o3.month.date = structure(c(16953, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16953, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16922, 16922, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16922, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16953, 16953, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16922, 16922, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 16953, 
      16953, 16953), class = "Date"), o3.month.date.previous = structure(c(16922, 
      16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 
      16892, 16892, 16922, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 
      16892, 16892, 16892, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 
      16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 
      16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16892, 16892, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16892, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16892, 
      16892, 16892, 16922, 16922, 16892, 16892, 16892, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16892, 16892, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 16922, 
      16922, 16922, 16922, 16922), class = "Date"), 
      aid = c("a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", 
      "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725", "a725"), 
      oid = c("o11816", 
      "o20077", "o20077", "o20077", "o20077", "o20077", "o20077", "o20077", 
      "o20077", "o20077", "o20077", "o23696", "o24697", "o28255", "o29968", 
      "o29968", "o29968", "o29968", "o29968", "o29968", "o29968", "o29968", 
      "o36383", "o36383", "o36383", "o36383", "o36383", "o36383", "o36383", 
      "o36481", "o36481", "o37147", "o37761", "o37761", "o37761", "o37761", 
      "o38480", "o38480", "o38480", "o38480", "o38480", "o38480", "o38480", 
      "o38480", "o38729", "o38904", "o38904", "o38904", "o38904", "o38904", 
      "o42403", "o42403", "o42403", "o42403", "o42403", "o42403", "o42403", 
      "o42403", "o42579", "o43113", "o43255", "o43255", "o43486", "o43486", 
      "o44068", "o44068", "o44068", "o44068", "o44474", "o44474", "o45552", 
      "o47039", "o47039", "o47039", "o47039", "o47039", "o47039", "o47039", 
      "o47082", "o47082", "o47209", "o47209", "o47209", "o47209", "o47209", 
      "o47209", "o48228", "o48509", "o48943", "o48943", "o48943", "o48943", 
      "o48943", "o48943", "o49126", "o49126", "o49126", "o49126", "o49126", 
      "o49126", "o49890", "o50413", "o50505", "o50505", "o51150", "o51835", 
      "o51835", "o52116", "o52116", "o52116", "o52116", "o52116", "o52116", 
      "o52116", "o52116", "o52116", "o52260", "o52260", "o52606", "o52670", 
      "o53341", "o53341", "o53395", "o53969", "o53969", "o55166", "o55166", 
      "o55166", "o55761", "o55761", "o55761", "o55761", "o55761", "o56077", 
      "o57530", "o57574", "o57574", "o57574", "o57688", "o57722", "o57722", 
      "o57862", "o57862", "o57862", "o58501", "o58567", "o58567", "o58567", 
      "o59423", "o59423", "o59843", "o60553", "o60553", "o60553", "o60553", 
      "o60553", "o61995", "o62230", "o62230", "o62230", "o62839", "o63835", 
      "o63835", "o63835", "o64526", "o64526", "o67971", "o67971", "o67971", 
      "o67971", "o68299", "o68299", "o68846", "o68887", "o69530", "o69530"
      ), 
      o3.cpt = c("c3354", "c742", "c750", "c3480", "c565", "c740", 
      "c3462", "c730", "c729", "c562", "c3478", "c3453", "c3354", "c484", 
      "c740", "c750", "c3730", "c3472", "c565", "c562", "c3478", "c729", 
      "c565", "c731", "c740", "c750", "c3478", "c562", "c3766", "c3407", 
      "c3397", "c3468", "c3470", "c3478", "c3468", "c3469", "c717", 
      "c563", "c718", "c750", "c745", "c562", "c3488", "c3487", "c3531", 
      "c1226", "c1413", "c1333", "c1349", "c1414", "c723", "c725", 
      "c742", "c565", "c3730", "c562", "c728", "c708", "c3306", "c3354", 
      "c3438", "c3407", "c3356", "c3407", "c1312", "c1226", "c1216", 
      "c1228", "c1239", "c1234", "c534", "c731", "c562", "c565", "c729", 
      "c740", "c3478", "c750", "c3456", "c3450", "c717", "c563", "c562", 
      "c718", "c745", "c750", "c3501", "c748", "c562", "c3489", "c750", 
      "c745", "c717", "c563", "c562", "c750", "c718", "c3489", "c717", 
      "c745", "c3335", "c3472", "c3472", "c3478", "c1154", "c3424", 
      "c3356", "c731", "c3478", "c729", "c562", "c742", "c739", "c565", 
      "c750", "c728", "c3411", "c3412", "c3377", "c3422", "c3478", 
      "c3480", "c3503", "c3435", "c3406", "c3730", "c3478", "c3480", 
      "c750", "c563", "c562", "c745", "c717", "c3342", "c2276", "c3357", 
      "c3407", "c3730", "c3337", "c3430", "c3407", "c3730", "c3407", 
      "c3357", "c3468", "c3356", "c3407", "c3730", "c3407", "c3430", 
      "c1066", "c750", "c731", "c562", "c742", "c732", "c17", "c1327", 
      "c346", "c402", "c3440", "c3517", "c3730", "c3513", "c2569", 
      "c2565", "c256", "c362", "c343", "c390", "c1060", "c1167", "c289", 
      "c1067", "c133", "c151")), 
      row.names = c(NA, -176L), 
      class = "data.frame")

  sample_cpts <-
    c("c3354", "c742", "c750", "c3480", "c565", "c740", "c3462", 
      "c730", "c729", "c562", "c3478", "c3453", "c484", "c3730", "c3472", 
      "c731", "c3766", "c3407", "c3397", "c3468", "c3470", "c3469", 
      "c717", "c563", "c718", "c745", "c3488", "c3487", "c3531", "c1226", 
      "c1413", "c1333", "c1349", "c1414", "c723", "c725", "c728", "c708", 
      "c3306", "c3438", "c3356", "c1312", "c1216", "c1228", "c1239", 
      "c1234", "c534", "c3456", "c3450", "c3501", "c748", "c3489", 
      "c3335", "c1154", "c3424", "c739", "c3411", "c3412", "c3377", 
      "c3422", "c3503", "c3435", "c3406", "c3342", "c2276", "c3357", 
      "c3337", "c3430", "c1066", "c732", "c17", "c1327", "c346", "c402", 
      "c3440", "c3517", "c3513", "c2569", "c2565", "c256", "c362", 
      "c343", "c390", "c1060", "c1167", "c289", "c1067", "c133", "c151"
    )

  set.seed(100)

 pcs <- 
    data.frame(
      o3.cpt = sample_cpts,
      PC1 = runif(length(sample_cpts), min = -3, max = 3),
      PC2 = runif(length(sample_cpts), min = 1, max = 10),
      PC3 = runif(length(sample_cpts), min = -4, max = 2),
      PC4 = runif(length(sample_cpts), min = -9, max = 8),
      PC5 = runif(length(sample_cpts), min =  4, max = 9)
    )
```

## Current code for the extended dataset:

```
 d1 <-
    d  %>% 
    # filter(aid == 'a725') %>%
    ddply('aid', function(x){
      
      mean_diff <- 
        x  %>% 
        # filter(o3.month.date == '2016-05-01')
        ddply('o3.month.date', function(i){
          
          past <-
              x %>% 
              filter(o3.month.date == i$o3.month.date.previous[1]) %>% 
              # select(o3.cpt, aid, o3.month.date, o3.month.date.previous, PC1, PC2, PC3) %>%
              select(o3.cpt, starts_with('PC')) %>%
              distinct
            
            current <-
              i %>% 
              # select(oid, o3.cpt, aid, o3.month.date, o3.month.date.previous, PC1, PC2, PC3) %>%
              select(o3.cpt, starts_with('PC'))%>%
              distinct
            
            intersect <- intersect(past$o3.cpt, current$o3.cpt)
            
            past <- 
              past %>% 
              filter(!(o3.cpt %in% intersect)) %>%
              .$o3.cpt
            
            current <- 
              current %>% 
              filter(!(o3.cpt %in% intersect)) %>%
              .$o3.cpt
            
            pairs <- 
              expand.grid(
                past,
                current
              )
          
          if(nrow(pairs) == 0){
            output <-
              data.frame(mean_diff = NA)
          }
          
          if(nrow(pairs) > 0){
            
          sum_diff <- 
            pairs %>%
              ddply(c('Var1', 'Var2'), function(j){
                
                p <-
                  pcs %>%
                  filter(o3.cpt == j$Var1[1]) %>%
                  select(starts_with('PC')) %>%
                  t %>%
                  data.frame %>%
                  .$.
                
                c<-
                  pcs %>%
                  filter(o3.cpt == j$Var2[1]) %>%
                  select(starts_with('PC')) %>%
                  t %>%
                  data.frame %>%
                  .$.
                
                data.frame(diff = sum(abs(p - c)))
                
              })
            
            output <-
              sum_diff %>%
              summarise(
                mean_diff = mean(diff, na.rm = T)
              )
          }

          output
          
        })
      
      mean_diff
      
    }, .parallel = T)
  
  d1
```

Comment: The extended dataset and the current code for the extended dataset have been added to address the shape of the original data, requested by @Jon Spring.

Comment: An error in the code was fixed just now! My apologies for the mix-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the pairwise Manhattan distance between the matrices made up of the `past` and `current` observations. `Rfast::dista` is a very fast implementation. The following runs in less than 0.0002 seconds.

```
pairs$diff <- c(
  Rfast::dista(
    as.matrix(numbers[match(past, numbers$o3.cpt), -1]),
    as.matrix(numbers[match(current, numbers$o3.cpt), -1]),
    type = "manhattan"
  )
)
```

Timing:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dista = {pairs$diff <- c(
    dista(
      as.matrix(numbers[match(past, numbers$o3.cpt), -1]),
      as.matrix(numbers[match(current, numbers$o3.cpt), -1]),
      type = "manhattan"
    )
  )}
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>   expr     min      lq     mean  median       uq     max neval
#>  dista 177.101 181.401 187.5551 183.301 185.4515 346.101   100
```

Comment: Hi @jblood94, Thank you very much for your response. As you suggest, it works faster than the answer from @Jon Spring, but you are simply getting the matrix by submitting the `numbers` data frame by the length of `past`, without matching `o3.cpt`. As a result, your code does not work exactly with my original dataset. Would you be able to make modification to address this issue? When you make the modification, would it result in similar processing time? Thank you again for your help in advance.

Comment: Would this following code work?     as.matrix(numbers[numbers$o3.cpt %in% past,  ] %>% select(-o3.cpt)),
      as.matrix(numbers[numbers$o3.cpt %in% current,] %>% select(-o3.cpt)),
      type = "manhattan"

Comment: So you would like it to work if `numbers$o3.cpt` had been defined as, e.g., `o3.cpt = sample(c(past, current))` instead of `o3.cpt = c(past, current)`?

Comment: I updated the answer using `match` so the order of `numbers` does not have to match `c(past, current)`.

Comment: thank you very much for your update! I will try it now. Just one clarification question. Would this work when the length of `past` vector is different from the length of `current` vector? I am not familiar with `dista` function, and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, it would. `dista` does pairwise, so the result will be a matrix where the number of rows equals the number of rows in the first matrix, and the number of columns equals the number of rows in the second matrix.

Comment: One more note: this assumes `pairs` was formed using `expand.grid` as in your example code.

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick rewriting using reshaped data and vectorized functions, and is about 60x faster (from 8 sec to 0.13 sec) for this example data and results in identical `diff` column.

The performance advantage increases to 2000x when I increase `past`/`current` length from 20 to 100, using the `dtplyr` variation below: 0.09 sec instead of 185 sec.

```
library(tidyverse)
pairs_rows <- pairs %>% mutate(row = row_number())
pairs_rows %>%
  left_join(
    pairs_rows %>% 
      pivot_longer(-row) %>%
      left_join(numbers, by = c("value" = "o3.cpt")) %>%
      group_by(row) %>%
      summarize(across(starts_with("PC"), ~abs(diff(.)))) %>%
      mutate(diff = rowSums(across(starts_with("PC"))))
    ) %>%
  arrange(Var1, Var2) # to replicate example output order
```

Some additional gains from wrapping that in `dtplyr`, which I presume would be much larger for larger data:

```
library(dtplyr)
pairs_rows <- pairs %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% lazy_dt()
# <same last block>
```

Comment: Hi @Jon Spring, Thank you very much for your help! Indeed it works MUCH faster than the original code. While I love your solution, it is still slow, so I am waiting for the follow-up of jblood94 to find a faster version. Thank you very much for your prompt help!

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the "shape" of your data / problem and what needs to run 700k times? It might be possible to squeeze out much higher performance if there is any way to combine the data to allow you to do the expensive operations (like pivot_longer) fewer times.

Comment: I will make a example dataset and update my post. Thank you very much for trying to help me!

Comment: In the extended dataset, the original d has 705,505 observations. The extended example dataset has only subset of observations, including only one `aid` and selected `o3.month.date`.  There are more than 700 PC columns and more than 3,000 unique `o3.cpt` ids for original `pcs` dataframe.

Comment: Currently, I am using @jblood94's code as it now works quite fast.  If we can make it more efficient, it would be great. Once again, I sincerely appreciate your help.